# Diverting water that falls thru a deck (under deck ceiling)

Tags: deck, joists, gutters

I just put a patio under my deck and now want to keep water from getting on it. I'd like to install an under deck ceiling, however, there's only really 1 or 2 options for a gutter even though there will be 3 sections of under decking.

I was thinking about using vinyl sheet flashing to create pans between joists and divert water from 2 outside sections to the 3rd inner section (night picture with V brace) and just install 1 gutter.

Does anyone have any ideas other then that? Going to attach a picture of all 3 sections. Ignore the existing under decking in the 1 picture, Im removing that for a zip-up system. Thanks[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Regardless the suggested solution, I'm thinking it's not a good idea to collect water under the deck, so close to the joists and decking.  I'm in Fla. and with our rains there would always be a damp and steamy environment under the deck boards.  Running the rain to a gutter helps , but I'm still not sure this is a good idea.

Comment: I think that's part of the risk of installing an under decking ceiling on a pre-existing deck. Ideally I would have had something installed when the deck was putting in(over the joists, under the decking) but I had no idea that was an option and my contractor never mentioned it. So it's kind of my only option at this point if I want a dry patio. Maybe during the winter I'll remove some of the ceiling, it just snaps in so might not be too bad

Answer (score 1):

In a similar situation, we ended up using polycarbonate corrugated sheeting like this one.  We decided we could do with the small amount of light that came filtering down and it's fairly cheap and easy to install.  And we could divert the water to the outer end of the deck.  Admittedly, we put it on before the deck, which made it easier.

[image: Sheet]

Comment: How did you secure the sheeting to the joists? Did you bow the sheet to create a U shape and screw them in?

Comment: screwed up the ridges into the joists, with screws meant for it.  They have a rubber type washer on them.  And put a spare washer on top.

Comment: Just gotta make sure you leave some slope on the sheeting; you can use spacers between the sheeting and joists.